# The name of a TV movie about a dead detective whose spirit seeks help from a woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I only saw it in passing while channel surfing; no name, no clear idea of time period [but I saw it in the 1990s] and I can't recall any of the actors. It *looked* like a television movie, but it *could* have been a small budget film.

**Last Detail:** The Ghost detective at first couldn't interact with anything, but then surprised himself when he picked up a framed picture casually.

Does anyone know what this might be?

Comment: [Randall and Hopkirk (Deceased)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_and_Hopkirk_(Deceased))?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, the old series was too old and the new series too new. Besides, the partner of the ghost detective was a _female_ whom [I think] he ended up sleeping with. At the very least, he kissed her goodbye before "moving on" at the end of the film.

Comment: Justin Case? I can't remember if he could touch a picture frame

Comment: @DannyMcG can you link me to a trailer or tell me more about it, please?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Case_(film)

Comment: @DannyMcG This _Sounds similar_ to it, yes, but I would have _remembered_  George Carlin in the role; the man was younger, brown hair. And this was DEFINITELY NOT a Disney series or film; the content was a little too adult, like Prime Time TV stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the movie you're looking for, [*Love Can Be Murder*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104764/?ref_=adv_li_tt) (1992)

> Elizabeth Bentley is a successful lawyer who suddenly has some
> "punkish" daydreams of being "Rambo" right around the time her
> clueless boyfriend Brad asks her to marry him. After a therapy
> session, she quits her job to the surprise of her family and Brad, and
> goes into the detective business, opening her own private-eye office.
> Unfortunately, the ghost of the private-eye who owned the office still
> lingers and Elizabeth's the only one who can see or hear him. At
> first, she becomes an unwilling partner in Nick Peyton's unfinished
> investigation, but then she finds herself falling for the salty, but
> dead, guy.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you describe how this movie matches the description provided in the question?

Comment: The schtick with the picture frame is about 16 minutes in

Comment: Yep, this is it.  Like I said, small budget TV. Thank you very much for this answer.

Answer (score 5):

A long shot, but I'd suggest this is the film Ghost with Patrick Swazye, Demi Moore and Whoopi Goldberg.

The plot revolves around the ghost of a murdered man (Swazye) trying to protect his lover (Moore) and uncover some sort of bank fraud if memory serves. The film was made in 1990 which would fit your timescale and Swayze's character cannot at first interact with the physical world until he accidentally knocks over a picture frame, a scene which approximates what you describe.

At the conclusion there is a kiss between the ghost and the female character before the ghost moves on.

This would have been a relatively big budget film at the time. The effects seem very dated now which might give the impression of it being low budget.

It maybe be too high production values to fit but here is the trailer on youtube

Comment: ohhhhhhhh no, partner; I **quite** remember Ghost! It's one of my sisters' top favorite supernatural romance movies. Demi Moore's best role, honestly. But thank you for your effort.